# C# - Insert DataSet into a SQL Table

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have a DataSet that I fill with values from a XML-file. I would like to insert the values then into a SQL table. How do I do that?

Here is how I fill my DataSet:

```
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        dataset.ReadXml(xmlfile);
        customer.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're ever going to do is inserts, then the simplest way is to just loop through the rows in the `DataTable` and create and execute a `DbCommand` for each row.  The specific syntax to use depends on the kind of database you're using; for SQL Server, it might look like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO T (A, B, C) VALUES (@A, @B, @C)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   conn.Open();
   foreach (DataRow r in myTable.Rows)
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = sql;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", r["A"]);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B", r["B"]);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C", r["C"]);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

This glosses over many, many possible complicating factors, e.g. exception handling, filtering out rows with the wrong `DataRowState`, calling `AcceptChanges` on the `DataRow`, updating identity columns with the value assigned by the database, and so on.  There's a lot to understand in ADO.NET, and that stuff's in there for a reason.  But if all you're going to do is insert rows, and the `DataColumn` objects in your `DataTable` have the right names and types and proper values for `Size` and `AllowDbNull`, and there are no foreign-key relations involved, and you're not going to encounter duplicate primary keys with existing data in the table, the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a stored procedure for your insert and then create a method that traverses the data set, and sets the parameters of your stored proc and then executes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to loop through the dataset and perform inserts.

You can obviously do this with a sproc, and you just pass along the parameters, or with LINQ.

Either way should work.

Comment: How can I loop though the DataSet?

Comment: The same way you would loop through the rows in a database and populate it.

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on you existing Data access Layer.

If one doesn't exist i would look more towards LinqtoSQL rather than using Stored procedures, Stored procedures are more difficult to manage

Answer (score -1):

Simple,

Just use the DataSet.ReadXml() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx

Now if your xml is different from your schema, then your most likely going to have to loop and fill your schema specific dataset, then save as needed.

Comment: I use the DataSet.ReadXml() method to fill my DataSet.